# How can I prove this proposition of linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

Good afternoon! I have to show this proposition:

1) Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ a non singular matrix and $PA=LU$, $P$ permutation matrix, $L$ a lower triangular matrix with $1$ on its diagonal and elements below the diagonal equal or lower than one, $U$ an upper triangular matrix.
Show that: $$\|A\|_F\leqslant\|U\|_F\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}.$$

And I have to answer this question:

2) Is $$\|A\|_{\infty}=\max_{(i,j)\in\{1,\ldots,n\}^2}|A_{i,j}|$$ a matrix norm?

I think that number two is false, but I don't know how to prove that and in number one I don't have any idea...
Will someone help me? Please! I´m desperate

Comment: "Good afternoon": do you have an idea of the range of time zones within the various people reading there ? ;-)

Comment: Why do you think $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ isn't a norm on $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: $\| A\|_\infty=\|A^T\|_1$

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET haha sorry, i just thought of my own time zone :(

Comment: @Sheol because there is no summatory,  like the ones defined on wikipedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Problem 1, you probably need $P$ to be the permutation matrix corresponding to using row-pivoted LU factorization. Since 
$$
\|A\|_F = \|PA\|_F
$$
then you can use
$$
\|A\|_F \le \|L\|_F \|U\|_F.
$$
Now use the fact that $L$ was determined using row-pivoted LU to give an upper bound on the entries of $L$ and therefore an upper bound on $\|L\|_F$.

For Problem 2, first perhaps check all the properties of a norm. Depending on your definition of "matrix norm", you might want to check sub-multiplicativity.

Edit: Misread problem 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! but i really don´t understand how can i show an upper bound of the entries of L...

Comment: Try performing the row-pivoted LU by hand on a 3x3 matrix, perhaps, to see what the entries of L look like.

Comment: Ok! i will try that to get an idea! :)